# How can "strange" ROP gadgets be found in a normal DLL? Compilers would never do this. (Return-oriented programming)

Tags: assembly, dll, x86, reverse-engineering, machine-code

The gadget:

```
pushad
ret
```

from a certain DLL makes no sense to me in a legit program.

Assuming the DLL is legit, how is it possible for the gadget to be found by automatic search?  An example of a function uses it may be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The instruction encoding is:

```
60  pushad
c3  ret
```

So wherever these two bytes occur, a `pushad; ret` gadget obtains.  For example, this instruction could reasonably exist in SSE code:

```
66 0f 60 c3  punpcklbw xmm0, xmm3
```

See the `60 c3` gadget in it?  Alternatively, the gadget could obtain from some immediate.  For example, suppose there is some variable at `0x4800c360` and we try to load its address:

```
b8 60 c3 00 48  mov eax, 0x4800c360
```

See the gadget again?

There are tons of other ways this gadget could appear in perfectly normal code.

Comment: Or even just something like `add eax, 0x60; ret` e.g. from a `return foo+96;`